# How do I mput and overwrite with FileZilla CLI PRO?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, sftp, filezilla

I have FileZilla CLI Pro as an SFTP client that I'm using in scripts run by scheduled tasks.

So how do I tell it, in my script, to overwrite when using mput ?

```
  set cli.prompt.trust_hostkey=1
  connect sftp://SomeUser:SomePassword@SomeServer
  cd IN
  mput  .*

  disconnect
```

Works until the file exists. Then it prompts for an overwrite. If it's a script run from a task, the task freezes there.

https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/filezilla-pro-cli/how-to-transfer-files-with-filezilla-cli/#ConnecttransferfilesCLI says there's an option for dealing with an existing file.
-e is the option and the value to overwrite is o

so ... `mput -eo .*`
shuts down with an "unknown option" message

```
mput -e:o .*
```

does likewise.

How does one use this option?

Comment: What about `-e o`?

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you!